# Sonata Admin image upload issue

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata

I have a problem when I try to upload an image to an entity.

**ENTITY**

```php
<?php

namespace app\PibeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;
use Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media;

/**
 * Pibe
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class pibe
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

  /**
 * @var string
 * @var \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
 */
private $imagen;

  /**
 * @var string
 * @var \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
 */

private $logoEs;

  /**
 * @var string
 * @var \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="LAZY")
 */
private $logoEn;


 /**
 * @var string
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @ORM\Column(name="titulo", type="text",nullable=true)
 */
private $titulo;

      /**
 * @var string
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @ORM\Column(name="script", type="text", nullable=true)
 */

private $script;


 /**
 * @var string
 */
private $scriptEn;


 /**
 * Set imagen
 *
 * @param string $imagen
 * @return ImagenesHome
 */
public function setScript($script)
{
    $this->script = $script;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get imagen
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getScript()
{
    return $this->script;
}


     /**
 * Set imagen
 *
 * @param string $imagen
 * @return ImagenesHome
 */
public function setScriptEn($scriptEn)
{
    $this->scriptEn = $scriptEn;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get imagen
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getScriptEn()
{
    return $this->scriptEn;
}



 /**
 * @var string
 */
private $tituloEn;


 /**
 * @var string
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @ORM\Column(name="texto", type="text",nullable=true)
 */
private $texto;

 /**
 * @var string
 */
private $textoEn;

    /**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="activo", type="boolean")
 */
private $activo;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ranking", type="integer")
 */
private $ranking;


 /**
 * @var string
 * @Gedmo\Locale 
 */
private $locale;



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


/**
 * Set imagen
 *
 * @param string $imagen
 * @return BannerHome
 */
public function setImagen(Media $imagen=null)
{
    $this->imagen = $imagen;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get imagen
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getImagen()
{
    return $this->imagen;
}




/**
 * Set imagen
 *
 * @param string $imagen
 * @return BannerHome
 */
public function setLogoEs(Media $logoEs)
{
    $this->logoEs = $logoEs;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get imagen
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getLogoEs()
{
    return $this->logoEs;
}

/**
 * Set imagen
 *
 * @param string $imagen
 * @return BannerHome
 */
public function setLogoEn(Media $logoEn)
{
    $this->logoEn = $logoEn;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get imagen
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getLogoEn()
{
    return $this->logoEn;
}

/**
 * Set titulo
 *
 * @param string $titulo
 * @return BannerHome
 */
public function setTitulo($titulo)
{
    $this->titulo = $titulo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get titulo
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTitulo()
{
    return $this->titulo;
}

/**
 * Set titulo
 *
 * @param string $titulo
 * @return BannerHome
 */
public function setTituloEn($tituloEn)
{
    $this->tituloEn = $tituloEn;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get titulo
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTituloEn()
{
    return $this->tituloEn;
}

/**
 * Set texto
 *
 * @param string $texto
 * @return BannerHome
 */
public function setTexto($texto)
{
    $this->texto = $texto;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get texto
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTexto()
{
    return $this->texto;
}



/**
 * Set texto
 *
 * @param string $texto
 * @return BannerHome
 */
public function setTextoEn($textoEn)
{
    $this->textoEn = $textoEn;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get texto
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTextoEn()
{
    return $this->textoEn;
}

  /**
 * Set activoBoolean
 *
 * @param string $activoBoolean
 * @return BannerHome
 */
public function setActivo($activo)
{
    $this->activo = $activo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get activoBoolean
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getActivo()
{
    return $this->activo;
}

/**
 * Set ranking
 *
 * @param integer $ranking
 * @return BannerHome
 */
public function setRanking($ranking)
{
    $this->ranking = $ranking;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ranking
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getRanking()
{
    return $this->ranking;
}

public function setTranslatableLocale($locale) { 


    $this->locale = $locale;


}

}
```

**ADMIN**

```php
<?php

namespace app\PibeBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class PibeAdmin extends Admin
{
/**
 * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
 */
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        //->add('id')
        ->add('titulo')
        //->add('texto')
        ->add('activo')
        ->add('ranking')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param ListMapper $listMapper
 */
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{   
    $listMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('titulo',null,array('required'=>false))
        //->add('imagenEs')
        ->add('imagen',null,array(
            'template'=>"PibeBundle:Default:imagen.html.twig"
        ))
        ->add('activo',null,array('editable'=>true))
        ->add('ranking')
        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
                'delete' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}

/**
 * @param FormMapper $formMapper
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $idioma=$this->getRequest()->getLocale();

    $formMapper
    ->add('imagen', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'label'=>'Imagen'

                     ), array(                       
                    'link_parameters' => array(
                    'context' => 'pibe',
                    'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image'

                        )
                    )
                )

    ;


    if($idioma=='es'){
            $formMapper         

                ->add('logoEs', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'label'=>'Logo Español'

                     ), array(                       
                    'link_parameters' => array(
                    'context' => 'pibe',
                    'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image'

                        )
                    )
                )
                ->add('logoEn', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'label'=>'Logo Ingles'

                     ), array(                       
                    'link_parameters' => array(
                    'context' => 'pibe',
                    'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image'

                        )
                    )
                )

              ->add('titulo','textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor'),'label'=>'Titulo Español','required'=>false))
              ->add('tituloEn','textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor'),'label'=>'Titulo Ingles','data'=>'','required'=>false))
              ->add('script','text',array('label'=>'Script Video Español','required'=>false))
              ->add('scriptEn','text',array('label'=>'Script Video Ingles','data'=>'','required'=>false))
              ->add('texto','textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor'),'label'=>'Texto Español','required'=>false))
              ->add('textoEn','textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor'),'label'=>'Texto Ingles','data'=>'','required'=>false))

                ;
        }else{
            $formMapper 

                ->add('tituloEn','textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor'),'label'=>'Titulo Ingles','data'=>'','required'=>false))
                ->add('titulo','textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor'),'label'=>'Titulo Español','required'=>false))
                ->add('scriptEn','textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor'),'label'=>'Script Video Ingles','data'=>'','required'=>false))
                 ->add('script','text',array('label'=>'Script Video Español','required'=>false))
                 ->add('textoEn','textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor'),'label'=>'Texto Ingles','data'=>'','required'=>false))
                ->add('texto','textarea', array('attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor'),'label'=>'Texto Español','required'=>false))




                ;
    }
    $formMapper
        ->add('activo')
        ->add('ranking')
    ;



    $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
    $em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    if($idioma=='es' && $this->getSubject()->getId()!=null){    


        //$titoriginal=$em->getRepository('HomeBundle:ImagenesHome')->find($this->getSubject()->getId());          
        // $titoriginal->setTranslatableLocale('en');
        //$em->refresh($titoriginal);


       //buscamos su traduccion en la tabal de traducciones.
       $repository = $em->getRepository('Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Translation');
       $translations = $repository->findTranslations($this->getSubject()); 
       //rellenamos el campo con la traduccion.
       if(count($translations)>0){

          if(array_key_exists("titulo",$translations['en'])){
            $formMapper->get('tituloEn')->setData($translations['en']['titulo']);
          }     
         if(array_key_exists("texto",$translations['en'])){
           $formMapper->get('textoEn')->setData($translations['en']['texto']);
          } 
         if(array_key_exists("script",$translations['en'])){
           $formMapper->get('scriptEn')->setData(trim($translations['en']['script']));
          }               
       };


    }else if($idioma=='en'  && $this->getSubject()->getId()!=null){

       $titoriginal=$em->getRepository('PibeBundle:Pibe')->find($this->getSubject()->getId());
       //cambiamos el locale a 'es' para coger el texto en español
       $titoriginal->setTranslatableLocale('en');
       $em->refresh($titoriginal);
       //una vez que lo cogemos, volvemos a cambiar el locale a 'en'
       $formMapper->get('tituloEn')->setData($titoriginal->getTitulo());
       $formMapper->get('textoEn')->setData($titoriginal->getTexto());
       $formMapper->get('scriptEn')->setData(trim($titoriginal->getScript()));

       $titoriginal->setTranslatableLocale('es');
       $em->refresh($titoriginal);

    }





}

/**
 * @param ShowMapper $showMapper
 */
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('titulo')
        ->add('texto')
        ->add('activo')
        ->add('ranking')
    ;
}


public function prePersist($object) {


        $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');


        //insertar en español.
        $object->setTitulo($object->getTitulo());
        $object->setTexto($object->getTexto());
        $object->setscript($object->getscript());
        $object->setTranslatableLocale('es');
        $entityManager->persist($object);
        $entityManager->flush();

        //insertar en ingles.
        $object->setTitulo($object->getTituloEn());
        $object->setTexto($object->getTextoEn());
        //$object->setscript($object->getscriptEn());
        if(!$object->getscriptEn()){
            $object->setscript(' ');
        }
        else{
            $object->setscript($object->getscriptEn());
        }
        $object->setTranslatableLocale('en');
        $entityManager->persist($object);
        $entityManager->flush();


}

public function preUpdate($object) {


        $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
        $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');


        //insertar en español.
        $object->setTitulo($object->getTitulo());
        $object->setTexto($object->getTexto());
        $object->setscript($object->getscript());
        $object->setTranslatableLocale('es');
        $entityManager->persist($object);
        $entityManager->flush();

        //insertar en ingles.
        $object->setTitulo($object->getTituloEn());
        $object->setTexto($object->getTextoEn());
        //$object->setscript($object->getscriptEn());
        if(!$object->getscriptEn()){
            $object->setscript(' ');
        }
        else{
            $object->setscript($object->getscriptEn());
        }
        $object->setTranslatableLocale('en');
        $entityManager->persist($object);
        $entityManager->flush();

 }


}
```

If I upload an image of 1500x1000 its works perfect:
[image]
[image]

But if the image is 1920x1080 it doesn´t works:
[image]
When I click crear it doesn´t add the image:
[image]

The php returns an error 500 from the server,but the image is in uploads/media. And I haven´t set a size(height/widht) limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probles os this malfunction is the php extension **php_fileinfo**,with it disabled I get the error,with it enabled all works as expected